# Extract ID's from string

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple strings like this :

> [13] Glass with digitizer (iPhone 5), [106] Battery (iPad 4), [192]
>   2GB DDR3 1067 MHz (Memory)

And I don't know how can I simple extract ID's from string to array?

Comment: And what have you tried and where is the id in this string.?

Comment: Perhaps make use of `preg_match_all`?

Comment: you'll have to explode it twice once on the basis of commas and then the brackets i guess

Comment: Numers in [] it's ID's ;)

Comment: @KubaŻukowski: Is this a single string or an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$input  = '[13] Glass with digitizer (iPhone 5), [106] Battery (iPad 4), [192] 2GB DDR3 1067 MHz (Memory)';
preg_match_all('/\[(\d+)\]/', $input, $matches);
$output = array_map('intval', $matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 13
  1 => int 106
  2 => int 192
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and then manipulate the array to get rid of the `[]`

```
$string = "[13] Glass with digitizer (iPhone 5), [106] Battery (iPad 4), [192] 2GB DDR3 1067 MHz (Memory)";
preg_match_all("/\[[0-9]*\]/",
    $string,
    $out);
array_walk_recursive($out[0], 'cleanSquareBrackets');
print_r($out);

function cleanSquareBrackets(&$element) {
    $element = str_replace(array("[", "]"), "", $element);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 106 [2] => 192 ) )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = "[13] Glass with digitizer (iPhone 5), [106] Battery (iPad 4), [192] 2GB DDR3 1067 MHz (Memory)";
preg_match_all('!\[\d+\]!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Additionally you can get it in a single string

```
$numbers = implode(',', $matches[0]);
```

Comment: I bet because `\d+` will match also `5` from `iPhone 5`, etc

Comment: Fixed the regular expression